# How to complete jQuery event before running AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Context**

On my website, users can go to the "search users" page, where they can search for any user's username, which will make the username pop up in a div with the id `#here`. When the user keys down in the input field with the id `#search`, the current usernames on the page are removed (`$("#here").html('')` is the code used to remove the usernames) and the function should then run, like so:

```
$("#search").keyup(function() { //when user inputs value into search bar

    offset = 0; //when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, more usernames are called in. Whenever the user inputs a new value, I reset the offset so that its value doesn't pile up over time.

    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#here").html(''); //empty previous usernames
    searchUsers(x); //get users

});
```

This is the function that gets the usernames:

```
function searchUsers(x) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'includes/suggestUsers.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'q='+x+'&offset='+offset,
        success: function(data) {

            data.forEach(function(item) {

                if (item.error == undefined) {

                    let newContent = 
                    "<div class='user-links-container'>"+
                        "<div class='userImgContainer'>"+
                            "<img src='images/"+item.image+"'>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<a href='userProfiles.php?user="+item.uidUsers+"&id="+item.idUsers+"' class='userLinks'>"+item.uidUsers+"</a>"+
                    "</div>"+
                    "<br>";

                    let appended = $(newContent).appendTo("#here");

                }

            });

        }
    });

}
```

**The Problem**

I'm having trouble removing the HTML content of a div before executing the next AJAX call. On my local server, this function basically works fine. But on my live website, the server is MUCH slower, so what ends up happening is, when the user types really quickly, there are a certain number of usernames that are returned for each time the user keys down, but the previous usernames are not cleared first.

So, if there was only one user on my site with the username "person", when you type "p" into the input field, the username "person" would show up. Then, when you type the "e" to get "pe", the original username "person" should be removed from the div where the usernames are output. However, the problem is that the original username is NOT removed, and now there are two of the same exact usernames being displayed. When you type out the whole username, "p, e, r, s, o, n", this results in six of the same usernames being displayed for six characters in the username when I want only one to be displayed; the HTML should be cleared after each text input so that only the most recent input remains. The div clears just fine when I go EXTREMELY slowly, but other than that, the previous usernames are not cleared (you can go to [this link](https://writingboxco.com/searchUsers.php) to check out the problem on my website).

**The Question**

Is there a way to make a chain out of the events so that the HTML ALWAYS clears before the function runs? I've already tried using promises, which doesn't work; the same problem occurs:

```
$("#here").html('').promise().done(function() {

    searchUsers(x); //get users

});
```

I've also tried using callback functions, which doesn't work:

```
$("#here").html('', searchUsers(x));
```

I've also tried placing the `$("#here").html()` code within the AJAX success callback itself. Although this effectively clears the previous usernames, the problem with that is that I'm also using the `searchUsers(x)` function to get more username results when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, so I don't want to clear the usernames that are currently listed when the user scrolls. This is the scroll code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

        var usernames = $("#here .user-links-container").length;
        //console.log(usernames);
        if (usernames >= 15) {

            offset = offset + 15;

            var text = $("#search").val();
            searchUsers(text);

        }

    }

});
```

I previously had two separate functions: one that calls the original usernames (`searchUsers()`) and one that got usernames after scrolling (`searchMoreUsers()`), but I reduced it to one (only `searchUsers()`) because I thought that was more efficient and having two functions seemed unneccessary. However, this might be the best option to potentially fix this problem. Thank you to whoever gives a crack at this problem. Let me know any ideas.

Comment: Implement debouncing so you don't send the AJAX request until the user pauses for a moment.

Comment: @Barmar I just got around to learning debouncing and it worked like a charm. Thanks!